# Vuetify data tables search not working

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Im new in Vue and Vuetify. I use vuetify data table in my project. Everything working fine except the Search options. I use everything as the documentation. But still not get any solution.

As the basic requirements I use these code to adding search

**Template**

```
          <v-text-field
            v-model="search"
            append-icon="search"
            label="Search"
            single-line
            hide-details
          ></v-text-field>

         <v-data-table
          :headers="headers"
          :items="sales"
          :search="search"
          :rows-per-page-items="rowsPerPageItems"

          row
          wrap
          class="elevation-1"
        >
```

**Script**

```
data(){
      return{
        search: '',
      }
  }
```

Here is the complete code
https://github.com/Shakilzaman87/pukucrm/blob/master/src/components/sales/Sales.vue

Answer (score 29):

Vuetify should warn you in the console about this:

> [Vuetify] Headers must have a value property that corresponds to a
>   value in the v-model array in "v-data-table"

So you can fix the search option by adding values:

```js
headers: [
  { text: 'Item Name', value: 'item_name' },
  { text: 'Unit Price', value: 'price' },
  { text: 'Quantity', value: 'quantity' },
  { text: 'Customer', value: 'customer' },
  { text: 'Created', value: 'timestamp' },
  { text: 'Total', value: 'total' },
  { text: 'Action', value: 'item_name' }
]
```

(data from your repo)

Comment: Thanks. I don't know how I missed that. It's the first thing I saw when I went back to the example.

Comment: love you :) Thank you so much